# Loopback uppercase property does not exist

Tags: javascript, postgresql, loopbackjs

I've got an issue using loopback, I created a model that fit a table I've got in my postgreSQL database and I managed to connect to this database but when I try to get any Item from my table it says:

[image]

[image]

the problem is that in my model I got the property ELECTRICITY and the request is for "electricity". I've looked up in their documentation but I didn't see anything to force the uppercase for the property. Does someone know how can I fix that? (I have to use uppercase field in my database and cannot change that)

Thanks.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: There isn't much code to show I used loopback to generate a model and added my Postgresql database to my datasource file, the connection to this database is fine but the request are not done properly the request are done with only lowercase value whatever I do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use node-postgres (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), with this you can custom your request and use uppercase.

Comment: please put this as comment, not as an answer

Comment: 'You must have 50 reputation to comment'

Comment: well said :) sorry